# Can automatically connect to paired bluetooth device when in range?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, android-bluetooth, android-broadcastreceiver

I have two Android phones. I want to make an auto connection between them via Bluetooth. For example,

> I have my android phone which paired to another Bluetooth. When I put these phone near together, they need to detect Bluetooth device, and automatically connect to a selected android phone (known Adress/MAC/Paired before). I don't need to connect it again. I want this kind of connectivity in my Android application.

I google and found some related reference, but they are did not solve the issue yet. I think that I need to create a thread/service to automatically connect Bluetooth when they are in range. However, I can not implement it. If you have a good solution, please let me know. Thank you

[Automatically connect to paired bluetooth device when in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569156/automatically-connect-to-paired-bluetooth-device-when-in-range)

[Find already paired bluetooth devices automatically, when they are in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810582/find-already-paired-bluetooth-devices-automatically-when-they-are-in-range)

```
   /**
     * The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and changes the title when
     * discovery is finished
     */
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
            // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

These broadcast receivers will fire only after the discovery process runs.

Discovery can be started in two ways: either manually in Bluetooth settings, or programatically by calling `BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery()`. However, the documentation states that:

> Device discovery is a heavyweight procedure. New connections to remote Bluetooth devices should not be attempted while discovery is in progress, and existing connections will experience limited bandwidth and high latency. Use `cancelDiscovery()` to cancel an ongoing discovery. Discovery is not managed by the Activity, but is run as a system service, so an application should always call `cancelDiscovery()` even if it did not directly request a discovery, just to be sure.

This implies that discovery should be done as a one-off procedure, not continuously running in the background—apart from slowing down other Bluetooth connections, it will drain the battery quickly.