# How to know when Bluetooth device is available

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

We have an app that connects to a Bluetooth scanner (Motorola CS3070), its currently connecting and working fine but when the scanner goes to sleep after a certain amount of time because of inactivity the users are complaining/expecting the app to be able to automatically detect that its available again and just connect to it.

From everything I have [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569156/automatically-connect-to-paired-bluetooth-device-when-in-range) there is no way to get alerted when a device is in range again aside from a Bluetooth LE device which this is not.

Now I could run a thread in a service trying to connect to the device every (n)seconds but that's obviously going to kill the battery of the device and with doze/OS battery optimizations its not always guaranteed to work because it can be killed.

So my question is; is there really no way that I can get notified when a Bluetooth device is in range to connect to it again?

Comment: Is the scanner connected via SDK or as a HID device?

Comment: Option to look into: Google Smart Lock: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6093922?hl=en

Comment: @MorrisonChang scanner is connected as a SPP device, then the app connects to it via the bluetooth api