# Phone BLE background for auto device connection

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, smartphone

i have some questions for ble conneciton between smartphone with bluetooth earphone.

after pairing/bonding the bluetooth earphone, when i turn on bluetooth earphone, my smartphone automatically connect to the bluetooth earphone.

how it can be? the smartphone periodically try to connect (send connect request packet) to paired devices?

i don't think that job includes advertising/scan because the connection has completed so quickly right after bluetooth earphone turn on.

maybe.. i think the smartphone periodically try to connect to paired devices..

is it right?

Comment: One possible way is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26569231/7473793